# ng-show hide based on return value by a function

Tags: angularjs

```
$scope.checkbit = undefined;
$scope.showHide = function(permissionrequired){
 for(var i=0; i< userpermissions.length; i++){
  console.log(userpermissions[i].name);
  if(userpermissions[i]=== permissionrequired)
         $scope.checkbit = 1;
 }
return $scope.checkbit;
}}
```

`$scope.userpermissions` is an array of assigned permissions to the current user.

Forexample:

["Create", "Show", "Update", "Delete"]

or

["Create", "Show", "Update"]

or

["Update", "Show"]

So, in case my current user had only ["Update","Show"], It should not show ones with ShowHide('Create') but it does if I have ShowHide('Show') in any of the li elements and worked just fine if the li elements that called ShowHide has 'Create' as the required permission.In that case it would hide elements that required 'Create' permission. But it fails if I add Show as required permission in any of the rest li elements.

I call it like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="navMode = 'createUser'" ng-show="showHide('Create')" ><strong>Create User</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="navMode = 'getUser'" ><strong>Get Users</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="navMode = 'createRole'" ng-show="showHide('Create')" ><strong>Create Role</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="navMode = 'getRole'"><strong>Get Roles</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="navMode = 'createPermission'" ng-show="showHide('Create')" ><strong>Create Permission</strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="navMode = 'getPermission'"><strong>Get Permissions</strong></a></li>

 </ul>
```

It works fine when I use only 'Create' or'Show'in li elements. But all of them show up if I use `ShowHide('Show')` in any of the remaining li elements.

What seems wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Show `userpermissions` (or `$scope.userpermissions` ?)... More, `$scope.checkbit` should better be a local scope variable (`var checkbit`), otherwise it's value will persist among calls, and, if you don't set it to `0` on start, it will be a problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your function to following

```
$scope.showHide = function(permissionrequired){
 var checkbit = 0;
 for(var i=0; i< userpermissions.length; i++){
  console.log(userpermissions[i].name);

  if(userpermissions[i]=== permissionrequired)
         checkbit = 1;
 }
return checkbit;
}}
```

Comment: Thanks .My bad. it was only because I did not set the checkbit back to undefined on next call of the function. Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need to create $scope variable checkbit. It is advised to have local variable it will make your function more clean and reusable.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip :) I will change it to that

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should probably change is to add `.name` to your if statement:

```
if(userpermissions[i].name=== permissionrequired)
```

Plz maken a http://jsfiddle.net/